# How to await and resolve actual data in loop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm looking to populate image-url and dimensions into the `ImageData` interface in typescript. The `getDimensionsFromImageUrl` is asynchronous call. How can I create `ImageData` array with no promises?

```
export interface ImageData {
    url: string;
    size: { width: number; height: number };
}

const images = [];
Array.from(inputFiles).forEach((file) => {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    const size = getDimensionsFromImageUrl(url);
    images.push({ url, size });
});

await Promise.all(images);
```

Using `await getDimensionsFromImageUrl(url);` had eslint error
`Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected.`
which I'm not able to resolve.

```
        Array.from(inputFiles).forEach(async (file) => {
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            const size = await getDimensionsFromImageUrl(url);
            images.push({ url, size });
        });
```

Comment: The problem is that `images` does not contain an array of promises; it contains an array of objects with a `size` property that is a promise` `Promise.all` doesn't wait for properties; it waits for promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With promise.all must use `.map` instead of `.forEach`. The `.map` return a new list, in this case it is list of promise.

```js
async function test() {
    const images = await Promise.all(Array.from(inputFiles).map(async (file): Promise<ImageData> => {
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        const size = await getDimensionsFromImageUrl(url);
        return { url, size };
    }));
    console.log(images);
}
```

Comment: The important part of the code changes made here is not `map` vs `forEach`; it's `async (file) => { ... await ...; return { url, size }; }`, which ensures the resultant array is an array of promises. The OP was using `push` inside the `forEach` which is roughly equivalent to `map`; they were just pushing objects rather than promises.

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type for the function:

```
function getDimensions(): Promise<void>
```

Also, `Promise.all` takes an iterable of promises as an input, but you are passing an array of `ImageData`, so that line might need to be removed or fixed.